# How to access a variable in an array of struct's

Tags: c, arrays, struct, structure

In the for loop below I attempt to access an array of structures stored in another structure but I continue to get an error that says. "struct list has no member head."

```
list* createList(int size)
{
    list* graph = malloc(sizeof(list));
    graph->size = size;
    graph->array = malloc(size * sizeof(vertex));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < size;i++){
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;
        return graph;
    }
}
```

The structures I am attempting to use are as follows.

```
struct vertex
{
    struct vertex *head;
};
typedef struct vertex vertex;
```

And

```
struct list
{
    int size;
    struct list* array;
};
typedef struct list list;
```

Comment: Your `list`'s `array` member should be a `struct vertex*`. Otherwise, I don't see any `vertex` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `list` member is of type list, when it should be of type `vertex`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any references to your struct vertex in struct list. I suspect that it should be

```
struct list{
     int size;
     struct vertex* array;
};
typedef struct list list;
```